# Error while loading shared libraries: libtcmalloc_minimal.so.4?

Tags: games, steam, libraries, shared-library

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04. I'm trying to run Portal 2 game for Linux from Steam, and it's not working; when I run it from terminal I get this error:

```
 error while loading shared libraries: libtcmalloc_minimal.so.4
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried installing the package? It's not installed by default. You'd use the command `sudo apt install libtcmalloc-minimal4`

Comment: Yes . I forget to add. Under this line terminal writes `wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64` too.

Comment: you may need to run `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386` and then `sudo apt install libtcmalloc-minimal4:i386` \*fingers crossed\* (the last `:i386` might not be necessary)

Comment: @Zanna Yeah it worked, thank you for help. And sorry you waited i had to try some levels. :D

Comment: hah no need to be sorry for that! great, glad that it worked!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The library is provided by the `libtcmalloc-minimal4` package which is available in repositories for 16.04 (and 16.10).

The game requires the 32-bit version of the library it seems (clue found in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/portal2/issues/227)) so if you're running a 64-bit system and haven't got any 32-bit packages, you'll need to run:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

and then install with the `:i386` suffix:

```
sudo apt install libtcmalloc-minimal4:i386
```

Comment: I can't comment on LiveWire's answer directly, but I just tried that solution and was told > Unable to locate package libtcmalloc-minimal4:i386 I even tried to [download the .deb file manually](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/lunar/main/base/libtcmalloc-minimal4) but the link was broken. Not sure where to go from here!

Comment: @pez Ubuntu is no longer supporting 32-bit, so I'm not sure either :(